# Why does console.log.apply() throw an Illegal Invocation error?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

When I execute the following code in Chrome 18 beta I get the error:

```
console.log.apply(this, ['message']);
```

> TypeError: Illegal invocation.

In Firefox 10 it works as expected.

In IE9 I get the error: `Object doesn't support property or method 'apply'`.

I'm guessing this has to do with how the browser has implemented `console.log`.

Why does it work in Firefox but not in Chrome and IE? I'm hoping someone can shed some light on the cause of this and its ramifications.

Here is [an executable sample](http://jsbin.com/ixoruw/edit#javascript,live) on JS Bin.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

`console` and `log` are host objects. Their behavior is implementation dependent, and to a large degree are not required to implement the semantics of ECMAScript.

FWIW, your jsBin fails in Chrome as well unless you change it to...

```
console.log.apply(console, ['message']);
```

but that seems to be that `log` simply anticipates a calling context of `console`.

Answer (score 11):

Here's an alternate solution. I'm not sure the case where there are no args works as expected.

```
function logr(){
    var i = -1, l = arguments.length, args = [], fn = 'console.log(args)';
    while(++i<l){
        args.push('args['+i+']');
    };
    fn = new Function('args',fn.replace(/args/,args.join(',')));
    fn(arguments);
};
logr(1,2,3);
logr();
logr({},this,'done')
```

Comment: why all this code when you simply have to pass console as this ?

Comment: apply has been there for over 20 years